# Git conflict while merging a feature branch after keeping it up to date

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, feature-branch

The solution for "Keep feature branch up to date" with git is, to merge the master into the feature branch from time to time, for example if a there is a change implemented in the master branch which is needed by the feature branch, correct?

I have done that once. So my history looks like:

```
master feature

now i want to merge
| |
| | file needsToBeChangedForNewFeature.php was changed here again
| |
|/| i get a conflict for each change since this point
| |
| | file needsToBeChangedForNewFeature.php was changed here
| |
|/
|
```

Now i want to finally merge this feature branch into the master, but i am getting a conflict in file "needsToBeChangedForNewFeature.php" for every line which was changed twi times (see git history example).

This seems somehow logic to me, as git cannot decide if to keep the semi-new or the really new version of the file.

So to sum up: older changes of a file in the feature branch are conflicting with the latest changes of the same file in the same feature branch.

But how can i avoid this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A single merge should give you at most one conflict event, possibly for every file.  What do you mean by `again in the period after the intermediate-merge` ?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I have updated the the description and history example. Hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: Was the file `needsToBeChangedForNewFeature.php` changed by both the feature and master branches?  If so, then what you are seeing is normal, even expected.

Comment: Are you doing a merge or re-base? As Tim said a merge should only result in a single conflict.

Comment: It was changed in both branches, but the change in the master is just because of this intermediatly merge, not because of any "real change".

And thats exactly what i am wondering about.

Comment: So to sum up: older changes of a file in the feature branch are conflicting with the latest changes of the same file in the same feature branch.

Comment: @user3507003 if you have been merging `master` into `feature` over and over again, there is no reason to merge `feature` back into `master`. `feature` is your new `master` branch. so just checkout `master` and `reset --hard `feature`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no change from the feature in master until the final merge, so there would not be any conflict (unless somebody is independently developing something else). From your description it looks like you somehow duplicate your changes in master, which you are not supposed to do.